# pandas DataFrame groupby + fillna producing very strange results

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting really strange results with a pandas DataFrame grouping operation.  What I want to do is group by index (my index is non-unique), and then fill null values appropriately.  This works in many cases but in some instances I am getting a strange behavior where an empty DataFrame is all that is returned:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sample', 'cooling_rate'], 
              index=['SYd', 'SYd', 'XNa', 'Xna', 'Qza_new', 'Qza_new'],  
              data=[['SYd', 3], ['SYd', 3], ['XNa', 3], 
                    ['XNa', 3], ['val1', 'val3'], ['val1', None]])

res = df.groupby(df.index).fillna('1')

#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: []
#Index: []
```

However, if I change the DataFrame ever so slightly, by renaming the index item 'QZa_new' to 'qza_new':

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sample', 'cooling_rate'], 
              index=['SYd', 'SYd', 'XNa', 'Xna', 'qza_new', 'qza_new'],  
              data=[['SYd', 3], ['SYd', 3], ['XNa', 3], 
                    ['XNa', 3], ['val1', 'val3'], ['val1', None]])

res = df.groupby(df.index).fillna('1')
#        sample cooling_rate
#SYd        SYd            3
#SYd        SYd            3
#XNa        XNa            3
#Xna        XNa            3
#qza_new   val1         val3
#qza_new   val1            1
```

The result is a properly grouped, filled DataFrame as expected.  I can't make any sense of this behavior, and I'm not getting any sort of "error".

With more experimentation, it appears that the key is definitely in my DataFrame index line:

```
    index=['SYd', 'SYd', 'XNa', 'Xna', 'qza_new', 'qza_new'],
```

It appears that the second to last value has to be earlier in the alphabet than the last value.  In other words,

```
    index=['SYd', 'SYd', 'XNa', 'XNa', 'a', 'b']
```

works and returns a filled in DataFrame, but:

```
    index=['SYd', 'SYd', 'XNa', 'XNa', 'c', 'b']
```

returns an empty DataFrame.  But why?

I suspect I must be missing something obvious, but I have no idea why I'm seeing this behavior.

Update:

This issue appears to be known: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14955  Hopefully will be fixed next release.

Comment: It seems like bug. Btw, first works too, if not sorted in `groupby` - `res = df.groupby(df.index, sort=False).fillna('1')`

Comment: You might want to search for this bug and report it if not already here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: Very interesting bug. I even tried assigning new column with same result: `df.assign(test=df.index). groupby('test').fillna('1')`. What is it about the case sensitivity of *Q*???